# Proof explanation - Erdös-Szekeres (1960)

Tags: proof-explanation

At [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1960-09.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj63Jyb7L_5AhUzi_0HHT5iAXcQFnoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3eKeqq48UQ0RhjvG0DXYIm), on Section 2, it is constructed a set of $2^{n-2}$ points in the plane such that they do not contain a convex $n$-gon.

I am not able to grasp it. I get lost when it says:

*Suppose now that $P_i, (i = 1, \dots,r)$ is a non-empty subset of $S_{k_i}, 1\leq k_1<\dots<k_r<n-1$ and such that $P=\cup_{i=1}^{r} P_i$ forms a convex polygon. Since
the slope of lines within each $S_k$ is positive, $P_i$ for $1 < i < r$ consists of a single
point and $P_1$ must form a concave sequence, $P_r$ a convex sequence. But then
the total number of points in $P$ is at most
$$k_1 + (k_r - k_1 - 1) + (n-k_r) = n-1$$*

Seems to be really simple, but (i)  where are the $2^{n-2}$ points derived from? (ii) how is derived the conclusion from the argument? Any clarification to help me understanding the proof would be really welcomed.

Thanks!

**Edit**

It has been detected by @aschepler that the paper linked is incomplete. A free link to the complete paper, or some site where the proof is showed, or an answer with the full proof would be welcomed.

Comment: Something does seem missing, and I notice that PDF jumps from page 54 to page 57 of the original publication.

Comment: @aschepler you are right! Then I am a bit relieved, I felt a bit dumb... I will try to find the complete paper. A bit strange that this one is incomplete. Thanks!

Comment: You can find this paper reprinted in a book called "The Art of Counting".

Comment: @SuzuHirose thanks, could you give a more specific reference? I have been unable to find it!